# Select a random row from Oracle DB in a performant way

Tags: database, oracle, database-performance

Using : 
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0

I am trying to fetch a random row. As suggested in other stackoverflow questions, I used `DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE` like this -

```
SELECT column FROM
( SELECT column 
  FROM table
  WHERE COLUMN_VALUE = 'Y' -- value of COLUMN_VALUE
  ORDER BY dbms_random.value 
)
WHERE rownum <= 1
```

But this query isn't performant when the number of requests increase. 
So I am looking for an alternative.

`SAMPLE` wouldn't work for me because the sample picked up through the clause wouldn't have a dataset that matches my `WHERE` clause. The query looked like this -

```
SELECT column FROM table SAMPLE(1) WHERE COLUMN_VALUE = 'Y'
```

Because the `SAMPLE` is applied before my `WHERE` clause, most times this returns no data.

P.S: I am ok to move some part of the logic to application layer (though i am definitely not looking for answers that suggest loading everything to memory)

Comment: What about `select column from (select column, row_number() over (order by column) as rw from table where column_value='Y') tb where rw = dbms_random.value(1,rw)` ? See if it is better and I will post it as an answer (if so)

Comment: Let me give this a try.

Comment: @JorgeCampos this doesn't seem to be giving me a random value, rw is always 1

Comment: consider [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39176705/1132334), it appears to fit well for your "inner where clause" requirement.

Comment: Yes, my bad. `select column from (select column, row_number() over (order by column) as rw from table where column_value='Y') tb where rw = dbms_random.value(1,(select count(*) from table))` rw in the random function would always evaluate to 1 for the first registry the subquery returns. This other solution may not be as good because of count, give it a try

Answer (score 3):

The performance problems consist of two aspects:

- selecting the data with `column_value = 'Y'` and
- sorting this subset to get a random record

You didn't say if the subset of your table with `column_value = 'Y'` is a large or small. This is important and will drive your strategy.

If **there are lots of records with**  `column_value = 'Y'` use the `SAMPLE` to limit the rows to by sorted.
You are right, this could lead to empty result - in this case repeat the query (you may additionally add a logic that increases the sample percent to avoid lot of repeating). *This will boost performance while you sort ony a sample of the data*

```
select id from (
select id from tt SAMPLE(1) where column_value = 'Y' order by  dbms_random.value )
where rownum <= 1;
```

If there **are only few records with**  `column_value = 'Y'` define an index on this column (or a separate partition) - this enables a effiective access to the records. Use the `order by  dbms_random.value` approach. *Sort will not degradate performance for small number of rows.*

```
select id from (
select id from tt where column_value = 'Y' order by  dbms_random.value )
where rownum <= 1;
```

Basically both approaches keep the sorted rows in small size. The first approach perform a table access comparable with **FULL TABLE SCAN**, the second performs **INDEX ACCESS** for the selected column_value.

Comment: There are some cases that return 10000 rows and some return just 10 for my `WHERE` clause. For a smaller number of matched rows, i would have to do `SAMPLE` quite a lot of time to get a random row, which i think would be an over-head. And I can't index it because Y isnt unique.

Comment: Well you **may** index a non-unique column (using non-unique index). The skew distribution makes it not easier, but you can combine both approaches. Simple give some tries with small sample size to catch the case with lot of result values (and to avoid a prohibitive sort). If the SAMPLE returns no result you may assume there is only a small number of values and you can fallback to the index access.